# Show syntax errors in knitr output?

Tags: knitr

I'm writing a description of R syntax, and I'd like to include some statements that include syntax errors, e.g.

```
if (n >= 2) 
{
    # if TRUE
}
else
{
    # if FALSE
}
```

(This is a syntax error at top level because the `if` is complete before the `else` is read.)  I'm trying to put this into a knitr document, but
even with `error=TRUE` it fails, because that option only affects run-time errors, not syntax errors.  Is there some reasonable way to get this to display what would be shown if I entered it at the console? I.e.
I'd like it to display something like

```
if (n >= 2) 
{
    # if TRUE
}
else
Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"
{
    # if FALSE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does part of what I want:  it reproduces the output from a syntax error, but it doesn't do all the markup that knitr would do, so the formatting is wrong.

```
parse_with_error <- function(text) {
  reportError <- function(e) {
    msg <- conditionMessage(e)
    line <- as.numeric(sub("^text:([[:digit:]]*):.*", "\\1", msg))
    col <- as.numeric(sub("^text:[[:digit:]]*:([[:digit:]]*):.*", "\\1", msg))
    cat(text[1:line], sep="\n")
    if (col > 1)
      cat(paste(rep(" ", col-1), collapse=""))
    cat("^\n")
    err <- sub("^text:[[:digit:]]*:[[:digit:]]*: ([^[:cntrl:]]*)\n.*", "\\1", msg)
    parseData <- getParseData(sf)
    lastToken <- parseData[nrow(parseData), "text"]
    cat(paste0("Error: ", err, ' in "', lastToken, '"'), "\n")
  }
  text <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\n"))
  sf <- srcfile("text")
  tryCatch(parse(text = text, keep.source = TRUE, srcfile=sf), 
        error = reportError)

}
```

This shows how it would be used:

```
parse_with_error(
"if (TRUE) {
  # do TRUE
}
else {
  # do FALSE
}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate R session to evaluate the code, e.g.

````
```{r, engine='Rscript', error=TRUE}
if (TRUE) 
{
    # if TRUE
}
else
{
    # if FALSE
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks, that's a very easy way to do it.  Just for fun (and to learn about knitr internals) I'm going to try to elaborate the function in my own partial answer; I think I can make it look a little more like the console than the Rscript method.